# How to join 2 tables together with a SQLAlchemy relationship using a 3rd table

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am developing a Python API on top of an already existing database. I am looking into the most efficient way to create a relationship between 2 tables where one of the tables has its data stored in other tables based on many-1 relationships.
I have currently designed my database models exactly in line with the current DB schema:

```py
class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = "A"
    id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    b = relationship("B", lazy="joined", uselist=False, backref="a")


class B(Base):
    __tablename__ = "B"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    a_id = Column(ForeignKey(A.id))
    d = relationship("D", lazy="joined", backref="b")


class C(Base):
    __tablename__ = "C"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    d = relationship("D", lazy="joined", backref="c")


class D(Base):
    __tablename__ = "D"
    b_id = Column(ForeignKey(B.id), primary_key=True)
    c_id = Column(ForeignKey(C.id), primary_key=True)
    value = Column(Integer)
```

What I would like to be able to do is to link A and D directly (which conceptually makes more sense) which I currently cannot do because D just contains IDs in a many-1 relationship with other tables.
My current solution keeps the above schema, links A to D via B. I then need to fetch details from C which causes overhead. Another solution I came up with was to redesign C and D so C is a child of D. This allows all data for an A id to be fetched by a single query.

Is there a standard way of joining 2 tables together via a relationship when the joining property exists in a 3rd table in a many-1 relationship with the 2nd?